# Will one cash transfer from a friend affect my visa application?

Tags: uk, visa-refusals

My UK tourist visa was refused once because I had unjustified cash deposits other than salary. This time and to avoid refusal I am trying to maintain my bank statement free of any cash deposits. But a friend of mine has transferred me an amount of £200. Now this £200 is showing at the very beginning of the 6 month bank statement. No other deposits were made for the rest of the 6 months. Will the UKVI question it or do I need to justify it?

Comment: I'm no expert but can you prove why your friend transferred you the money in the application? If so you will need to document that properly in the cover letter. Generally a unexplained bank deposit might look like a case of funds parking to the ECO. It also depends what £200 compares to your monthly income. For e.g if your monly income is £100  and you receive £200  from a friend it might raise suspicion. Maybe more experienced members can shed more light on this.

Comment: Yep, it depends a lot on your usual revenues and balance. If you make £5000 a month, nobody will care about £200. If it’s a significant amount compared to your income or it’s the difference between having the necessary funds for your trip or not, then it’s more likely to be an issue.

Comment: **No other deposits were made for the rest of the 6 months.** What does that mean? No transactions?

Answer (score 3):

Will this new cash deposit affect the new application? Yes.

Will the new application be denied? No one knows.

Your previous application was denied because your bank statement included unexplained cash deposits. A new application with the same flaw is not a recipe for success; given your recent refusal for this same conduct, your justification now may not be sufficient to convince the visa examiner of your *bona fides*.

You will increase your chances of success by having and showing a bank statement of 6 months with no oddities. Wait six months so your account has no non-salary deposits, then reapply.

Because non-salary deposits imperil your application, make sure your friend doesn't do this again.

Comment: Your answer seems a little extreme? £200 is not a huge amount of money, if this is a one-off and the OP has regular income well in excess of that, it's highly unlikely to be an issue.  If it's a loan repayment or something, just mention it in the application.

Comment: @lambshaanxy Your observation may well be correct, but we don't know what the OP's financial situation is. £200 may be a significant number compared to the OP's regular income. And the more explanation is required, and the less "regular" the application, the more likely it'll attract distrust and scrutiny.